# How to save output from groovyconsole in a file?

Tags: groovy, aem, groovy-console

I have installed groovyconsole in AEM and have bunch of stuff that I would like to save in a file as output.

Following [this](https://hashimkhan.in/aem-adobecq5-code-templates/groovy-script/) post, I tried:

```
def filePath = "/content/corporate/reports/output.csv"
File output = new File(filePath)

output.append('Hello world!')
```

I end up getting a FileNotFoundException. I created the file directly just to make sure, but that too didn't help.

Would appreciate some heads up on this. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are using a JCR path (node path). Using File means a file on the ‘file system’ and NOT a JCR path (node path). Are you trying to save to JCR? If so, that’s a different API

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the following:

- You may not have permissions to write to the folder specified. You should try first to write to a folder where you are absolutely have write access.
- maybe not all the directories leading to output.csv exist, you should make sure the folder tree exists by using `File.mkdirs()` like so:

---

```
def folderPath = "~/fff/eee/reports"
def folder = new File(folderPath)
def result =folder.mkdirs()

def filePath = "~/fff/eee/reports/output.csv"
File output = new File(filePath)

output.withWriterAppend{ out ->
    out.println 'hello there!'
}
```